# Reduce size of exported contourplot

Tags: plotting, export

Following the answer given [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97507/simple-contour-plot-with-variable-thickness), I am plotting contour lines in black/white:

```
data2 = Flatten[
   Table[{x, y, .8 (x + 1)^3 + .4 (y + 1)^2}, {x, -4, 4, .1}, {y, -4,4, .1}], 1];
width = 0.1;
ListContourPlot[data2, 
 Contours -> Flatten@Table[n + width {-.5, .5}, {n, -30, 30}], 
 ContourShading -> {White, Black}, PlotRange -> All, 
 ContourStyle -> Black]
```

I am then exporting the image. This is just a test data set. The real data set has 100.000 data points and thus the exported image is much larger.

Is there a way to either plot differently or change the plot such that the exported vectorized image is around a few MB?

Comment: What command do you use to export it?  When I enter `Export["cplot.pdf", [ListContourPlot[....] ]` the result is only 600kB

Comment: @JasonB Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is just a minimal example. The real data set is 100.000 entries long, that makes the size grow...

Comment: See my answer here [How to export this PDF figure with a small size](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51777/how-to-export-this-pdf-figure-with-a-small-size/51848#51848)

Comment: I found one alternative: To make a contourplot with every, say, 5th or 10th, datapoint... works fine

Comment: Ah very good! Then it's only fair if you show your solution as an answer.

Comment: That is one solution, but you can also keep your data and just rasterize before exporting to pdf, `Export["figure.pdf", Rasterize[yourplot, ImageSize -> 600]]` and toy with the size to find the right tradeoff.